# H2O: Can't done run_tcp_client.sh (example_client.py) with DriverlessAI's scorer.zip

Tags: python, h2o, driverless-ai

I am using the DriverlessAI(with H2O.ai) and trying to use scorer (which is a Diagnosis model made from DriverlessAI), but an error occurred.

When running run_tcp_client.sh, the error 
" File "example_client.py", line 5, in 
    from thrift import Thrift
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thrift'"
has occurred.

In the document(https://www.h2o.ai/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/driverlessai/scoring-package.html) it's written that it is enough to run run_tcp_client.sh after runing run_tcp_server.sh.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Thrift as per the [documentation](https://www.h2o.ai/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/driverlessai/scoring-package.html#prerequisites) you linked:

`The following are required in order to run the scoring package. [..] Apache Thrift (to run the TCP scoring service)`:

> Installing Thrift
>
> Thrift is required to run the scoring service in TCP mode, but it is
>   not required to run the scoring module. The following steps are
>   available on the Thrift documentation site at:
>   https://thrift.apache.org/docs/BuildingFromSource.

```
$ sudo apt-get install automake bison flex g++ git libevent-dev \
  libssl-dev libtool make pkg-config libboost-all-dev ant
$ wget https://github.com/apache/thrift/archive/0.10.0.tar.gz
$ tar -xvf 0.10.0.tar.gz
$ cd thrift-0.10.0
$ ./bootstrap.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

@EDIT:

Please check if you can run (in the folder where you have those scripts) this:

```
$ source client_env/bin/activate
$ python -c 'from thrift.transport import TSocket'
```

If you get the same exception then please run:

```
pip install -r client_requirements.txt
```

And try running the script again.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. And I could not explain in detail, sorry.

Comment: I did installing thrift, and I can run run_tcp_server.sh which used thrift.
So, I think python can't done the code "from thrift.transport import TSocket" .

Comment: @H.Doi sorry I'm not following - what is the exact error you're getting after running the example now?

Comment: @ Mateusz Dymczyk Error message is ｢File "example_client.py", line 5, in from thrift import Thrift ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'thrift'｣

I explain what I did below.
 1. prepared an EC2-instance on AWS (ubunts 16.0.4)
 2. install python3.6 (with command shown in "6.1 Prerequisites" in document)
 3. Install Thrift (with command shown in "6.1 Prerequisites" in document)
 4. run run_tcp_server.sh
 5. run run_tcp_client.sh and the above error occured.

Sorry to understand "thrift" or "Driverless AI".

Comment: @ Mateusz Dymczyk Sorry and Thank you for your advice.
I ran after @EDIT, and I noticed that the cause of the error was the failure to install pip.
　　　
After installed pip with command 'curl "https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py" -o "get-pip.py" ' and 'pip install -r client_requirements.txt' , I can do it.

Thank you very mach !!

Comment: @H.Doi no problem, hope you'll be pleased with DAI :-) also please "accept" this answer, so we know that you figured out your issue.